# md-select can't set selected value

Tags: angularjs, angular-material

I have a `md-select` set up as follows:

```
<md-select placeholder="Category" ng-model="current.Category" flex >
    <md-option ng-repeat="item in categories" ng-value="{{item}}">{{item.Name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

`@scope.categories` value is

```
[  
{  
  "Name":"Commercial & Industrial",
  "ParentId":null,
  "Categories":[  
     {  
        "Name":"Deceptive Marketing",
        "ParentId":19,
        "Categories":[  

        ],
        "Id":24,
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-08-06T07:49:53.0489545",
        "CreatedDate":"2015-08-06T15:49:51.707"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Aggressive Agents",
        "ParentId":19,
        "Categories":[  

        ],
        "Id":25,
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-08-06T07:50:10.0026497",
        "CreatedDate":"2015-08-06T15:50:08.63"
     }
  ],
  "Id":19,
  "ModifiedDate":"08/06/2015 @ 7:49AM",
  "CreatedDate":"08/06/2015 @ 3:49PM"
 },
 {  
  "Name":"Competitive Supply",
  "ParentId":null,
  "Categories":[  
     {  
        "Name":"Security Deposit",
        "ParentId":20,
        "Categories":[  

        ],
        "Id":21,
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-08-06T07:49:30.3966895",
        "CreatedDate":"2015-08-06T15:49:25.8"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Meter",
        "ParentId":20,
        "Categories":[  

        ],
        "Id":22,
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-08-06T07:49:34.6571155",
        "CreatedDate":"2015-08-06T15:49:33.3"
     },
     {  
        "Name":"Bill",
        "ParentId":20,
        "Categories":[  

        ],
        "Id":23,
        "ModifiedDate":"2015-08-06T07:49:41.7268224",
        "CreatedDate":"2015-08-06T15:49:40.357"
     }
  ],
  "Id":20,
  "ModifiedDate":"08/06/2015 @ 7:49AM",
  "CreatedDate":"08/06/2015 @ 3:49PM"
   }
]
```

The `md-select` works fine. But what I can't figure out is how to set select value. When I try setting the model `current.Category` to one of the values from the `$scope.categories` it doesn't get set.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The documentation isn't explicit, but you should use `ng-selected`. I've created a [codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/VLRweg) to illustrate, but basically:

```
<md-option ng-repeat="(index,item) in categories" ng-value="{{item}}"
           ng-selected="index == 1">    
    {{item.Name}}
</md-option>
```

This'll select the the second category (index 1 in your category array).

Comment: but how to get selected value?

Comment: As in the example above. Or, if its more complicated, write a function and attach it to `$scope`.

Answer (score 18):

You need to use **ng-model-options**, **trackBy** and choose a unique model field as a selector:

```
<md-select placeholder="Category" 
    ng-model="current.Category" 
    ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.Id' }" // <-- unique field 'Id'
    flex >
    <md-option 
     ng-repeat="item in categories" 
     ng-value="{{item}}">{{item.Name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

This solution is described in Angular Material's [official documentation](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#selects-and-object-equality).

Comment: what about wanting 2 unique model fields for trackby. is that possible?

Comment: A unique field is unique. If you need to use two fields, they are not unique. You could create a combined unique index with those two fields and use it.

Answer (score 4):

in order to set the default value of select you can use **ng-selected** and **ng-model**

```
    <md-select ng-model="vmIdPage.number">
             <md-option ng-value="mod" ng-repeat="mod in vmIdPage.initObject.listeModaliteMisePlace" ng-selected="{{ mod.id === vmIdPage.number.id ? 'true' : 'false' }}">
                {{mod.libelle}}
             </md-option>
    </md-select>
```

Comment: I used ng-selected="true" for selected all

Comment: I am assigning value like this 
$scope.ng-model = 'assigned value'. But this won't assign any value to it.

Answer (score 2):

This solution is simple if you are wanting to default to the first value in the drop down.

Use the `ng-select="$first"`. This will default the drop down to the first value.

```
<md-select placeholder="Categories" ng-model="current.category">
   <md-option ng-repeat="(index, item) in categories" value="{{item}}"
              ng-selected="$first">{{item.Name}}</md-option>
</md-select>
```

Here is a [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jxmPaP) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case adding `ng-model-options="{trackBy: '$value.id'}"` as described in the [docs](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect) did not work, as no initial value was set. 
By explicitly setting the model to the wished default value in the controller properly set the value as desired. This approach might be easier if you do not know up front the index of the element you want to display as pre-selected (using `ng-selected`). Of course you can evaluate it in the controller, but to me it seems more immediate to set the target element directly to the model.

**View:**

```
<div class="input-style-border">
   <md-select ng-model="vm.selectedGlobalFilter">
       <md-option ng-value="item" ng-repeat="item in vm.globalFilterValues">
            {{item.value}}
       </md-option>
   </md-select>
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
function initialize() {
        vm.globalFilterValues = globalFilterValues;
        vm.selectedGlobalFilter = TransferGlobalFilter.Worldwide;
    }
```

Where globalFilterValues are in the form:

```
[
  {key:"All", value:"All values" },
  {key:"Manager", value:"Manager"},
  {key:"HR", value:"Human resources"},
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use value in ng-option insted of ng-value

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you elaborate on this a little bit, maybe write some sample code?

Answer (score -3):

Like specified in the doc of [md-select](https://github.com/angular/material/blob/master/src/components/select/select.js) directive , you can use ng-model-options.

See this [post](https://github.com/angular/material/issues/2862)

Comment: You should elaborate your answer.