# How to set default value in md-select

Tags: angularjs, md-select

This is my angular code I want to set default value as 300mb

```
<label >RAM</label>
  <md-select ng-model="RAMVal">
    <md-option value="300mb" ng-selected="index == 1">300mb</md-option>
    <md-option value="400mb">400mb</md-option>
  </md-select>
```

Comment: Refer this link [md-select-cant-set-selected-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31881754/md-select-cant-set-selected-value)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Just add this

```
 ng-selected="true"
```

you can check in 
https://jsfiddle.net/rschmukler/0ju750xo/

Answer (score 0):

Just set ngModel(RAMVal) value to whichever option you want to be selected by default. ex : $scope.RAMVal = '300mb'; 
Reference Link : [mdSelect](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/api/directive/mdSelect#selects-and-object-equality)